# SWIG, Python and unicode strings

Tags: python, travis-ci, swig, tox

I am developing a Python module using SWIG and linking with a certain library.
I have a typemap like the following:

```
%typemap(in) MyStringType {
    char* buffer = 0;
    size_t size = 0;
    int alloc = SWIG_OLDOBJ;
    int res = SWIG_AsCharPtrAndSize( $input, &buffer, &size, &alloc );
    if (!SWIG_IsOK(res)) {
        SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_TypeError, "in method '$symname', expecting string");
    }
    $1.p = buffer;
    $1.n = size - 1;
}
```

I have some function that takes as parameter MyStringType as the parameter:

```
void myFunc(MyStringType type);
```

Then, when I create the python module I do the following in python 2.7:

```
myFunc("Test string")
```

However, when I try with Python 3.4 I get the following:

```
 TypeError: in method 'myFunc', expecting string
```

I could solve that by adding this to the swig interface file:

```
%begin %{
#define SWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_UNICODE_WCHAR
%}
```

That solved the problem. However I still need to add one more macro because some other functions require it. So, now it is like this:

```
%begin %{
#define SWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_BYTE_CHAR
#define SWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_UNICODE_WCHAR
%}
```

This would make me call myFunc like this:

```
myFunc(b"Test string")
```

And everything works fine when using tox in my pc, for python 2.7, 3.4 and 3.5, but it fails in travis-ci.
After removing the b before "Test string" it succeeds in travis-ci but fails in my pc.
In travis-ci I have: python: 2.7.6, 3.4.3
In my pc : python: 2.7.13, 3.4.8

Any idea why?

Comment: In travis the build fails with: myFunc(b"Test string"). In my pc the test fails with: myFunc("Test string")

Comment: Are you creating 2 different shared objects each linked with their respective python libraries, one for python 2.7 and another for python 3.4. The error you get looks like you have linked to the wrong python library.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Thanks for all the hints.
It was different swig versions.